# How upload images with ckeditor in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, ckfinder

i'm using laravel 5.2. and i installed CKEditor.
When i'm trying to instal CKFinder trought composer i get the next error:
ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package v3.4.4 requires laravel/framework ^5.5

Help to rezolve the problem...

Comment: upgrade your Laravel installation or use an older version of `ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package`.

Comment: Thanks, i updtated laravel to 5.5.

Comment: After updating laravel to 5.5 i get the next error:
 The requested package ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package 4 exists as ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package[dev-master, v3.4.4] but these are rejected by your constraint

Comment: I resolve the issue with composer. The right commande for composer.json is:
"ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package": "3.4.4", instead of:
"ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package": "4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue with composer. The right commande for composer.json is: "ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package": "3.4.4", instead of: "ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package": "4"